# add new section to lead to call api depending on the lead url

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud

I want to add new section to the leads to call api request depending on the lead website url

It's something like creating the web-based tab, but I want to ad inside the leads to get data from a website depending on the lead website url

Answer (score 0):

You can have VisualForce pages inline in a page layout, but the height is fixed and I generally don't find it to be an elegant solution, but it may work well in your case depending on what information you're bringing back and whether the length needs to be dynamic.

I'd implement this as a Visualforce page, and then use a formula field on the link to create a link to the page based on the Lead's URL. Users could then click this link to popup a new window with your page and information.